# how to get value selected in lightbox with magnifiq popup

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I'm trying to work out how I can get the value selected in a lightbox form, so it can be used in the parent window.

I'm using magnifiq popup, but I think the question is straight jquery.

The code that initialises the popup is shown below. It opens a popup which has an AJAX form in it. When that form completes via aJAX submission, I want to get the new id from the resulting data and update an element in the parent page.

I thought to use events, but there can be multiple of these links on a page, so I just want to pass it back to only the caller (the link in this case).

So just to reiterate:
1. Open popup. - done
2. Submit form which creates a new object. - done
3. When popup closes I want to get the value that was returned from the form and update the corresponding link element.

```
$(document).on('click', '.widget-configure a', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    var widget = $(this).parent().prev(".widget-selector").val();
    var _link = $(this);
    if (widget !== null)
    {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        var data = {"widgetId": widget};
        var template = Handlebars.compile(href);
        var targetUrl = template(data);

        $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: targetUrl
            },
            type: 'ajax',
            closeOnBgClick: false,
            callbacks: {
                close: function(ev){
                    alert('closed');

                }
            },


            cursor: 'mfp-ajax-cur',
            tError: '<a href="%url%">The content</a> could not be loaded.'
        }, 0);

    }else
    {

    }

})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you can get to the content of the form through the popup instance `content` property.

So I update the id field in the ajax form when it returns and then in the close action I get that updated field value:

```
callbacks: {
    close: function(ev){

        var id = $(this).attr("content").find('.widget-config-id').val();
        if (id != null && typeof(id) !== 'undefined' && id.length > 0)
        {
            // we update the link to an edit link
            _link.attr('href', '/admin/widgets/json/{{widgetId}}/configure/edit/' + id);

            // and update the hidden configuration id.

        }

    }
},
```